# how to print jquery JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some data which is coming from minicart.js and when i check with using console.log it shows following value like below:

```
[Product, Product, Product, Product]
0:Product {_data: {…}, _options: Array(0), _discount: 0, _amount: 300, _total: 600, …}
1:Product {_data: {…}, _options: Array(0), _discount: 0, _amount: 150, _total: 150, …}
2:Product {_data: {…}, _options: Array(0), _discount: 0, _amount: 4500, _total: 4500, …}
3:Product {_data: {…}, _options: Array(0), _discount: 0, _amount: 400, _total: 2800, …
```

My script which i am using are below:

```
<script>
paypalm.minicartk.render();
var items = paypalm.minicartk.cart.items();
console.log(items);
</script>
```

So now i want to show amout and data value in html. I have tried below but it is not working:

```
<script>
paypalm.minicartk.render();
var items = paypalm.minicartk.cart.items();
$("itemAmount").html('<span>+items.amount+</span>');
$("itemName").html('<span>+items.data.item_name+</span>');
</script>
```

Note: My item names are under the Product.

```
Product
 _amount: 300
 _data: 
    add: "1"
    amount:300
    cmd:"_cart"
    discount_amount:"0.00"
    href:"http://example.com/"
    item_name:"All Purpose Cream"
    quantity:2
    submit:"Add to cart"
 __proto__:Object
 _discount:0
 _eventCache:{change: Array(1)}
 _options:[]
 _total:600
 __proto__:Object
```

Comment: `$("itemAmount").html('<span>'+items[0].amount+'</span>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop for the above quest as shown below:

```
<script>
paypalm.minicartk.render();
var items = paypalm.minicartk.cart.items();
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
  $("#itemAmount").append('<span>'+items[i]._data.amount+'</span>');
  $("#itemName").append('<span>'+items[i]._data.item_name+'</span>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.